# Custom Date Format Not Available to my Date Field

Tags: 7, views, datetime

I'm sure I'm missing something super simple, but for some reason, my date field that I've created cannot make use of the "custom format" option in Views. I'm using D7 7.22 and the Date Module, 7.x.2.6

I've noticed that the field that I created is labelled differently than a normal date field which is "content: post date".

Mine is labelled, "Choose how users view dates and times"

The regular field is labelled simply "date format"

I've created a content type that has a date field with day, month, year, and time specified for each node. It doesn't matter which formatter I select - plain, time ago, date and time -  I do not have the option for a custom format for this field and I'm baffled. I can see the custom formats I created at admin/config/regional/date-time but no option for a custom format in Views.

I need to reformat the output of the values in contained in that field so that I can theme it appropriately, and will roughly be following this: http://highrockmedia.com/blog/theming-views-post-date-drupal-7-date-parts

Any ideas on why this would not be an available option? I've cleared all caches, removed and recreated the field - everything I can think of but I can't find anything on why I cannot use that field in Views.

You can see the difference in this screen grab: http://bit.ly/1cGQMkY

Thanks in advance

Comment: Your screen capture is gone.

Answer (score 2):

They seem to be build differently, you really can't do that I guess. But do this:

Add a new format at admin/config/regional/date-time/formats. Then add a new Date type at 
admin/config/regional/date-time and here select your new format. Then you can select this in the view.

Comment: Is there any way to add HTML to the custom format? The length also seems to be limited such that adding '<span class="day">' etc will run out of space...

Comment: Adding to the comment, I did a video tutorial on adding new formats at http://gleamly.com/article/drupal-date-api-creating-custom-date-format